# jQuery - Show id, based on selected items class?

Tags: jquery

I have a layout roughly as follows:

```
<div id="foo">

    <!-- a bunch of content -->

</div>


<div id="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumb-content1"></div>
    <div class="thumb-content2"></div>
    <div class="thumb-content3"></div>
</div>


<div id="content-1">
    <!-- some text and pictures, including large-pic1 -->
</div>

<div id="content-2">
    <!-- some text and pictures, including large-pic2 -->
</div>

<div id="content-3">
    <!-- some text and pictures, including large-pic3 -->
</div>

etc ....
```

On page load I want to show 'foo' and 'thumbnails' and hide the three content divs.

As the user clicks each thumbnail, I want to hide foo, and replace it with the matching 'content-x'.

I can get my head round jQuery show, hide and replace (although, bonus points if you want to include that in your example!). But how would I extract and construct the appropriate content id, from the thumbnail class, then pass it to the show hide code?

Comment: (The content is dynamically driven by a CMS. Also, I know there are thumbnail/gallery plugins, but they seem like overkill for this).

Comment: I don't understand why each thumbnail has a different *class* -- I'd make them all the same `class="thumb-content"` and each with its own *id* `<div id="thumb-content-1" class="thumb-content">` then trim the "thumb-" from the id of the click target, which would give me the id of the actual content div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your markup, you can do something like this:

```
$("[id^=content]").hide();
$("#thumbnails > div").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('class').replace('thumb-content','');
    $("#foo").html($("#content-"+id).html());
})​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

[You can see a demo working here](http://jsfiddle.net/cNM3S/)

This uses the [`^=` starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to hide the initial divs, and on click, uses [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to copy the content like you want.

If you have a *lot* of these, it's better to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which attaches a *single* event handler instead of `n` event handlers to every click-able `<div>`.  It would look like this:

```
$("[id^=content]").hide();
$("#thumbnails").delegate("div", "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('class').replace('thumb-content','');
    $("#foo").html($("#content-"+id).html());
});​
```

[Demo updated for that here](http://jsfiddle.net/cNM3S/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I just used the index from `.each()` to construct the id name:

```
$("div[id^='content-']").hide();

​$('#thumbnails').find('div').each(function(i,obj){
    $(obj).click(function(e){
      $("#foo").html($("#content-"+(i+1)).html());        
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

...and you can see also a [working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrxtV/) (Take that Nick!)

Comment: This depends a few things, for example the navigation divs being the *only* thing in the thumbnails div and the order being correct, if the class turns to say 01 or 02 if they get larger, they don't render in order...anything and this breaks, best to use the classes and IDs provided like the question asks for...

Comment: Touche sir, touche.  Yours is a more solid interpretation of the spec. +

Comment: +1 - All of what I said here may be things that are assured to be constant by the CMS and may *not* be an issue...from the example you can't tell, only the OP knows...but this is valid for the example :)

Answer (score 0):

Load Content by means of class and id

```
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");

      google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

            // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED (CALL IT ON LOAD)
            $(function() {
                $('.thumbs').click(function() {
                    var id = this.className.split(' ')[1];
                    $('#foo').html($('#' + id).html());
                });
            });

      });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="foo">

        00 00 00

    </div>


    <div id="thumbnails">
        <div class="thumbs content-1">Load 01</div>
        <div class="thumbs content-2">Load 02</div>
        <div class="thumbs content-3">Load 03</div>
    </div>


    <div id="content-1" style="display:none">
        01 01 01
    </div>

    <div id="content-2" style="display:none">
        02 02 02
    </div>

    <div id="content-3" style="display:none">
        03 03 03
    </div>

</body>
```

If I've read your post right, by clicking on the thumbs you want to load the content to #foo!
If this is correct, use the example posted:

1. This will run the code every time you click on an element with a class of "thumbs"

   $('.thumbs').click(function() {
2. This will split the classes of the clicked element and will grab to a variable the second one

   var id = this.className.split(' ')[1];
3. This will search for an element with an id equal to the grabbed class and retrieve it's content, sending it to #foo.

   $('#foo').html($('#' + id).html());

Note that the trick is to have the clicked element with a class name that's correspondent to and id element that contains the required content.

Hope this helps U!

Comment: Great working example, thanks, but Nick beat you to chosen answer :)

Comment: I'm a fan of Nick Craver's work for a while now... It's fair :)
(btw: I've vote is answer as well...)